# Generating a fictional panel data set

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to create a fictional panel data set, with 100 panel obervations (50 pairs), with the variables: panelID, country and year. This means that each panelID, should have the same country but a different year (what year does not matter, but let's say 4 year apart).

I have tried to do the following but it does not work.

```
panelID = c(1:50)   
year= c(2001:2010)
country = c("NLD", "GRC", "GBR")
DT <- data.table(expand.grid(panelID, year, country))
```

How should I do this?

Desired output, something like:

```
DT1 <- fread(
"panelID coutry year   
  1   NLD   2002
  1   NLD   2006      
  2   GBR   2001
  2   GBR   2005    
  3   GRC   2001             
  3   GRC   2005
  4   NLD   2004
  4   NLD   2008
  5   GBR   2006
  5   GBR   2010    
  6   GRC   2005             
  6   GRC   2009",
header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the intended result:

```
panelID = c(1:50)   
year= c(2001:2010)
country = c("NLD", "GRC", "GBR")

n <- 2

library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
data.table(panelID = rep(sample(panelID), each = n),
           country = rep(sample(country, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
           year = c(replicate(length(panelID), sample(year, n))))

     panelID country year
  1:      31     GBR 2010
  2:      31     GBR 2005
  3:      15     NLD 2005
  4:      15     NLD 2008
  5:      14     GRC 2003
  6:      14     GRC 2002
  7:       3     NLD 2010
  8:       3     NLD 2002
  9:      42     NLD 2010
 10:      42     NLD 2006
... 100 rows total
```

And for 4 years apart:

```
#for 4 years apart
set.seed(123)
years <- sample(2001:2006, length(panelID), replace = T)

set.seed(123)
data.table(panelID = rep(sample(panelID), each = n),
           country = rep(sample(country, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
           year = c(t(matrix(c(years, years+4), ncol = n))))
```